# How to pass set of values to POST request of REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api

I want to filter reports using REST api based on set of ids.So, I am storing all those ids in a set and passing it as a value like this :

```
request.setBody('{"reportMetadata": {"reportFilters": [{ "value": "'+setContactId+'","operator":"equals","column":"CONTACT_ID"}]}}');
```

But, it gives this error :

> [{"errorCode":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"[For the filter 1: The filter
>   value for ID (00328000005abcXXXX, 00328000005aXbcXXX,
>   00328000005aXbcXXX) is incorrect. Specify an ID that is 15 or 18
>   characters long, such as 006D000000CrRLw or 005U0000000Rg2CIAS.]"}].

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

From a brief reference to the [Filter Reports on Demand](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_filter_reportdata.htm) documentation it looks to me like you will need to build JSON of this form:

```
"reportBooleanFilter": "1OR2OR3",
"reportFilters": [
    {
        "value": "00328000005abcXXXX",
        "operator": "equals",
        "column": "CONTACT_ID"
    },
    {
        "value": "00328000005aXbcXXX",
        "operator": "equals",
        "column": "CONTACT_ID"
    },
    {
        "value": "00328000005aXbcXXX",
        "operator": "equals",
        "column": "CONTACT_ID"
    },
],
```

as there dos not appear to be an "in" [operator available](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=filter_operators.htm&language=en).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I can't go with this way as there are large number of ids to be passed.

Comment: @Smitha The docs say max 20 so yeah a problem.